# Existence of $\varphi$-related smooth vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

> Let $\varphi: N \rightarrow M$ be $C^{\infty}$ and let $X$ be a $C^{\infty}$ vector field on $N$. Suppose that $d\varphi(X(p))=d\varphi(X(q))$ whenever $\varphi(p)=\varphi(q)$. Is there a smooth vector field $Y$ on $M$ which is $\varphi$-related to $X$?

This is problem 20 in Chapter 1 of F. Warner's Manifolds, and unfortunately, it is one of the few that has me stumped. I tried to consider simple cases such as when $M = \mathbb{R},$ $f$ the inclusion map, and $N$ some interval in $\mathbb{R}$ to get an embedding. But that didn't lead to much. Are we supposed to find a general counterexample if it is false? Or perhaps it is true — in any case, I would appreciate if someone could give me a step in the right direction.

Comment: Is $\varphi$ assumed to be surjective?

Comment: @KennyWong, I suppose not — he makes no mention of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample, using the idea you described in your post.

Take $N = (0,\infty) $ and $M = \mathbb R$, and take $\varphi: N \to M$ to be the natural embedding $t \mapsto t$. Take $X$ to be the vector field $(1/t) \partial_t$ on $N$.

Because $\varphi$ is injective, the condition that $\varphi(t_1) = \varphi(t_2)$ implies $d\varphi(X(t_1)) = d\varphi(X(t_2))$ is satisfied vacuously.

Now if $Y$ is a vector  field on $M$ that is $\varphi$-related to $X$, then $Y(t) = (1/t)\partial_t$ for all $t > 0$. But then, $Y(t)$ cannot possibly be continuous at $t = 0$, and we have a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! For the last sentence, however, what is the contradiction? I agree that $Y(t)$ is not continuous at $t = 0$, but isn't the domain of $Y(t)$ all $t > 0$?

Comment: @AlexanderPope In your quote from the book, it says that $Y$ is a "smooth vector field on $M$", so I interpreted that to mean that the domain of $Y$ is the whole of $M$. Therefore, $Y$ must extend smoothly to $t = 0$ and beyond... (At least, this is one interpretation of what the book is talking about.)

Comment: OH! Thank you, this makes a lot of sense now. And that makes the problem a lot easier to think about in the first place. The problem is that in my class we are following this textbook; however, the instructor did not discuss extensions at all in lecture. So I am going to read that section of Warner now . . .